# Parameter name s: exception with Timer Triggered Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

**How do we debug an exception that is related to loading libraries prior to the first function executes?**

I'm getting the following exception when attempting to execute my function locally:

[image]

```
[7/12/2019 6:33:46 PM] Executed 'OnHydrateContainersTimerTriggered' (Failed, Id=e5f5324f-466c-423d-ba06-37b6b5637fea)
[7/12/2019 6:33:46 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: OnHydrateContainersTimerTriggered. System.Private.CoreLib: Value cannot be null.
```

I've been struggling many hours on attempts to figure out what's wrong.

Here's the full function:

```
public static class OnHydrateContainersTimerTriggered
{
    [FunctionName("OnHydrateContainersTimerTriggered")]
    public static async Task RunAsync(
        [TimerTrigger("%OnHydrateContainersTimerTriggered:TimerSchedule%")]TimerInfo timer,
        [Table("%OnHydrateContainersTimerTriggered:MaxConnConfig%")] CloudTable cloudTable, ILogger log)
    {
        var storageConnection = GetEnvironmentVariable("OnHydrateContainersTimerTriggered:StorageConnection");
        var currentBlobsPerContainer = await GetCountOfBlobsPerContainer(storageConnection);
        var maxBlobsPerContainer = await LoadConfigTable(cloudTable);
    }
}
```

**What am I doing wrong? Where is this exception getting triggered from?**

Perhaps this might be an issue specific to VS2019preview. I'll attempt with another version of VS, and will update.

Comment: Please read the `visual-studio-2019` tag.  It does not apply to this question.  "Do not use this tag unless you have a specific question about this version of VS".  You are not asking about VS2019 features or usage.

Comment: Can you try hardcoding the values that you're currently pulling from app settings / environment variables?

Comment: Could you provide the following information so we can investigate from back end?

- Function App version (1.0 or 2.0)
- Function App name
- Function name(s) (as appropriate)
- Region

If you don't want to give your function app name, you can do so privately.https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately

Comment: Could you post an example of your localsettings.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did nothing wrong here, I did some investigation as it is very odd indeed.

I came up on several posts on Github, one of them is this [post](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-microsoftgraph-extension/issues/101).

Apperently, if triggered at it's azure url it works fine, but not locally - **you should test it to see if it falls on your case as well.**

If it is your case, alot of developers are waiting on a fix from Microsoft to this issue and meanwhile, just don't use the methods locally, only through the azure url.